# Live update variable depending on form selection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I currently have the following form :

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
            <label for="categorie"> Tipul testului</label><br>
            <select name="categorie" class="selectpicker">
                <option value="1">Geometrie</option>
                <option value="2">Algebră</option>
            </select><br><br>
            <label for="cerinta"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Cerinţă</label>
            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="cerinta" name="cerinta" placeholder="Cerinţă"></textarea>
            <br>
            <label for="rezolvare"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Rezolvare</label>
            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="rezolvare" name="rezolvare" placeholder="Rezolvare"></textarea>
            <br>
            <label for="nr_raspunsuri"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Număr de raspunsuri</label>
            <select class="selectpicker" name="nr_raspunsuri">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>                
            </select>
            <br>


            <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-md-6">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" name="btn-add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Adăugare</button>
                        </td>
                            <td class="col-md-6">
                            <input type = "reset" class="btn btn-danger btn-block " label="Resetare"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </form>
```

What I am trying to do is to set a variable named `$nr_raspunsuri` to `1` or `2`, depending on the selection of the user without refreshing the page.

For example, if he selects `2` in the second select field, I want to set the variable `$nr_raspunsuri = 2`, so I can show one more input field in the form with an `if` in php. I think this can only be accomplished with AJAX. Is it true? If yes, how would you do it?

Comment: You can use pure javascript or J-Query if your dynamic input field in already on page. There is no need for Ajax call. Google for **onchange** of *select element*. Or if you want to know sample code let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` in **php will not run again until the page is reloaded**. You can achieve it by toggling the view with javascript - when option with value 1 is selected from first select hide the element which shouldn't be seen, if option with value 2 is selected show it. You can achieve it using [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) event.